# PHP contact form bug

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmailer, contact-form

I have a contact form using html and i also have a sendEmail.php file.
Everything works on the front end and notified that the email has been sent but it never seems to come to my inbox.
I can't identify why this is happening? 
Help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Here is HTML

```
           <div class="form-field">
                   <input name="contactName" type="text" id="contactName" placeholder="Name" value="" minlength="2" required="">
           </div>

           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-six tab-full">
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <input name="contactEmail" type="email" id="contactEmail" placeholder="Email" value="" required="">
                    </div>                         
                </div>
                <div class="col-six tab-full">              
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <input name="contactSubject" type="text" id="contactSubject" placeholder="Subject" value="">
                  </div>                               
                </div>
           </div>

           <div class="form-field">
                <textarea name="contactMessage" id="contactMessage" placeholder="message" rows="10" cols="50" required=""></textarea>
            </div> 

           <div class="form-field">
              <button class="submitform">Submit</button>

              <div id="submit-loader">
                 <div class="text-loader">Sending...</div>                             
                  <div class="s-loader">
                            <div class="bounce1"></div>
                            <div class="bounce2"></div>
                            <div class="bounce3"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
           </div>

        </form> 

        <!-- contact-warning -->
        <div id="message-warning"></div> 

        <!-- contact-success -->
        <div id="message-success">
           <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Your message was sent, thank you!<br>
        </div>
```

Here is the sendEmail.php

```
$siteOwnersEmail = 'info@jalina-digital.co.uk';


if($_POST) {

$name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));
$email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
$subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
$contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));

// Check Name
if (strlen($name) < 2) {
    $error['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
}
// Check Email
if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
    $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
}
// Check Message
if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {
    $error['message'] = "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
}
 // Subject
if ($subject == '') { $subject = "Contact Form Submission"; }


// Set Message
$message .= "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";
$message .= "Email address: " . $email . "<br />";
$message .= "Message: <br />";
$message .= $contact_message;
$message .= "<br /> ----- <br /> This email was sent from your site's contact form. <br />";

// Set From: header
$from =  $name . " <" . $email . ">";

// Email Headers
$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


 if (!$error) {

  ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
  $mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if ($mail) { echo "OK"; }
  else { echo "Something went wrong. Please try again."; }

} # end if - no validation error

else {

    $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? $error['name'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br />" : null;

    echo $response;

 } # end if - there was a validation error

 }

?>
```

And here is some JS.
         var ssContactForm = function() {

```
/* local validation */      
    $('#contactForm').validate({

        /* submit via ajax */
        submitHandler: function(form) {             
            var sLoader = $('#submit-loader');          

            $.ajax({    
              type: "POST",
              url: "inc/sendEmail.php",
              data: $(form).serialize(),

              beforeSend: function() { 
                sLoader.fadeIn(); 
              },
              success: function(msg) {
                // Message was sent
                if (msg == 'OK') {
                    sLoader.fadeOut(); 
                   $('#message-warning').hide();
                   $('#contactForm').fadeOut();
                   $('#message-success').fadeIn();   
                }
                // There was an error
                else {
                    sLoader.fadeOut(); 
                   $('#message-warning').html(msg);
                    $('#message-warning').fadeIn();
                }
              },
              error: function() {
                sLoader.fadeOut(); 
                $('#message-warning').html("Something went wrong. Please try again.");
                 $('#message-warning').fadeIn();
              }
          });           
        }

    });
 };
```

Comment: FYI your email regex appears to only allow only 1 or 2 character TLDs

Comment: What happen when you run mail commandline ?

Comment: Use try http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php to hope catch more informations ?

Comment: PHP has a built-in function to validate emails, have a look here : http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php

Comment: @AlexK. How so?

Comment: Many mail servers don't accept emails from any server. When they receive an email, the mail server can "ask" the server that's defined in the MX-record (of the senders domain) if the sending server is allowed to send emails as that domain or not.  Because of this, sending emails from any email (like from a form) won't work in many situations.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The email is being sent to and from the same server. my site is on my hosting provider who also provides me with 365 outlook

Comment: Are you using their SMTP as well?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Not sending through SMTP - if i did i would need to use something like PHPMailer, would this be a better option?

Comment: Using SMTP and a mail library like PHPMaiiler or Swift Mailer is usually much better than using PHP's `mail()`-function. When using SMTP, you will also get better error messages, in case something goes wrong. But then you will most likely need to send it through your email address with your username/password.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written has some errors.

1) In your HTML form it show `<button class="submitform">Submit</button>` you must just a name to that input example `<input type="submit" name="send" class="submitform">Submit</input>`

2) In your PHP sendEmail file `if($_POST)` must become `if(isset($_POST['send']))`

Accordingly making these corrections will solve. Also Note Sending mail in PHP will not instant receive msg this may take some time.

Comment: Having a button the way he does is valid. And his issue isn't that it doesn't try to send the email, but rather that he don't receive it (which means that both the button and the `$_POST`-check seems to work).